# Why do some scripts fail to remote when locked

Tags: powershell

I have one script that asks a few computers via invoke command once an hour for 7 hours and it works fine. The computer locks still runs.

I have other scripts that query thousands of computers and if the computers locked it's like permissions are blanked and it stops working. I can't explain it. And everything I Google pulls up bad information due to keywords. I don't have example code. But for example I'm listing a specific directory in every computer and it fails when I log out. I don't have 15 hours to wait for the script to finish. I am sorry for no code but I don't know where else to ask. Just some direction pointing and I can figure it out. Please.

Comment: To clarify: the problem is that the computer that's running the commands remotely locks due to inactivity, and then the remote commands are no longer run? Please describe the symptoms in more detail.

Comment: Without seeing some code or error output, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: You got it @mklement0.

Comment: Incorrigible1, there is no errors. It just stops getting whatever details I'm pulling.

Comment: So an obvious thing to check is whether the machine _goes to sleep_ in addition to locking. Again, please update your question which as much relevant information as possible.